# How can I test a Yii2 model in a library project?

Tags: unit-testing, activerecord, yii, yii2, phpunit

I'm trying to implement an adapter that is using a Yii model object extending `yii\db\ActiveRecord`. The object is passed as constructor arg to the adapter class.

My issue is now that I still couldn't figure out how to get this to work properly. I've even tried mocking it but got stuck because Yii is using lots of static methods to get it's objects. Sure, I could now try to mock them... But there must be a better way?

```
public function testSuccessFullFind(): void
{
    $connection = (new Connection([
            'dsn' => 'sqlite:test'
        ]))
        ->open();

    $queryBuilder = new \yii\db\sqlite\QueryBuilder($connection);

    $app = $this->createMock(Application::class);
    \Yii::$app = $app;

    $app->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getDb')
        ->willReturn($this->returnValue($connection));

    $userModel = new UserModel();
    $resovler = new Yii2Resolver($userModel);
    $result = $resolver->find(['username' => 'test', 'password' => 'test']);
    // TBD asserts for the result
}
```

The `UserModel` is used to find a user record internally.

This results in:

```
1) Authentication\Test\Identifier\Resolver\Yii2ResolverTest::testSuccessFullFind
Error: Call to a member function getDb() on null

vendor\yiisoft\yii2-dev\framework\db\ActiveRecord.php:135
vendor\yiisoft\yii2-dev\framework\db\ActiveQuery.php:312
vendor\yiisoft\yii2-dev\framework\db\Query.php:237
vendor\yiisoft\yii2-dev\framework\db\ActiveQuery.php:133
tests\TestCase\Identifier\Resolver\Yii2ResolverTest.php:31
```

The code above is obviously the WIP of a test case.

So how can I configure a test connection and get my ActiveRecord object to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass connection as argument of [`all()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#all()-detail) method:

```
$results = UserModel::find()->where(['id' => 1])->all($connection);
```

Comment: This is not going to help me because I would have to pass the ActiveRecord AND connection to the Adapter class I'm writing. Sorry, this has been my fault, the line with the find there is just there to test if the query works at all. I'm not intending to leave it there in the test, it's going to go into the adapter class. I've updated the code and question.

Comment: Well, you probably should allow to pass `Connection` instance to you adapter (as a optional parameter, same as `all()` does), so it could be used with different connection than defined in AR. For testing purpose you can just create custom AR model and override [`getDb()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#getDb()-detail) to return connection instance, without touching static app instance.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this already but was not sure if this is a common thing to do in Yii2? I want this lib / adapter to be easy and familiar to use for users of the framework. The architecture of the framework seems to be highly coupled and dependent, also all these static calls don't make it easy to mock. :(

Comment: If someone uses Yii2 AR, he probably has app initialized and AR uses `Yii::$app->db` by default, so the whole problem does not exist at all. Allowing optionally pass connection does not hurt convenience, but it makes it more flexible.